# Helm deployment with Envoy - Timeout fetching resource

Tags: kubernetes-helm, envoyproxy

We are using helm to deploy our application in conjunction with envoy and we are intermittently getting a timeout trying to fetch a specific resource, always the same one.
`gRPC config: initial fetch timed out for type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.Secret`
I was wondering if there is a way to increase the timeout by overriding the envoy configuration.
I was looking at this resource: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/security/secret but cannot figure out if I can override the `connect_timeout: 1s`.
Thank you.